# Can I query a view using value but not key?

Tags: couchdb

I have created a view named doc_view and when i query the view I'm getting results based on view paremeters (like startkey and limit etc)

```
{"total_rows":103,"rows":[
{"id":"1574031792000.doc","key":"d15836415514","value":{"r":"one"}},
{"id":"1574031832000.doc","key":"d15836418914","value":{"r":"seven"}},
{"id":"14259796657.doc","key":"d1583641`enter code here`8915","value":{"r":"eleven"}},

]
}
```

Is there any way where I can query the view based on values (that is r field?)

Answer (score 1):

Views can only be queried by key.  So you have two options: Write a new view that uses that value you care about as the key, or use a [Mango query](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/database/find.html).